# Reading an RGB formatted file into a buffer in RISCV (32-bit) assembly

Tags: image, assembly, riscv32, rars-simulator

I'm trying to read the RGB values from the file into an array, but when I check the buffer it's full of zeros instead of the values. First I tried it in C and then, implemented it in riscv assembly. I'm not sure what's causing this.

Here are the both implementations,

```
// reads a file with an image in RGB format into an array in memory
void read_rgb_image(char fileName[], unsigned char *arr)
{
    FILE *image;
    image = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    if (!image)
    {
        printf("unable to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fread(arr, 3, WIDTH * HEIGHT, image);
    fclose(image);
}
```

```
read_rgb_image:
    addi sp, sp, -4
    sw s0, 0(sp)

    la a0, filename
    li a1, 0    # read-only flag
    li a7, 1024 # open file
    ecall   
    mv s0, 
    
    la a1, buff # get array add.
    li a2, 3
    li a7, 63   # read file into buffer
    ecall
    
    mv a0, s0
    li a7, 57   # close file
    ecall
    
    lw s0, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 4
    ret
```

Comment: You're asking it to read 3 bytes from the file, do you see anything in those three bytes?  Also, need to check that Open ecall succeeded, can you verify that it does e.g. from single stepping, getting a good return value from the Open ecall.  If so, then what's in a0 after the read ecall?  Is it 3?

Comment: Yes, it's 3. I forgot to check if it fails. I will add that condition. I can not see what's in those bytes because it causes an exception. It says ' Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: address out of range 0x00000007'. Which is that line "lb a1, 0(a0)". a0 holds the file descriptor.

Comment: Um, there's no `lb` in the code you're showing.  In any case it is telling you that you are dereferencing a pointer that is bad.  A good pointer comes from either your global data, stack memory, or allocated memory; 7 is not a good pointer.

Comment: I added that part later. I'm kind of confused at the moment. Can you explain to me the good and bad pointers and what should I do? I'm a newbie and still learning riscv assembly.

Comment: Pointers are just unsigned numbers that refer to memory locations.  The `lb` instruction, among others, dereferences pointers, that one reads a single byte from the given memory location.  However, of all the possible pointer values (from 0 to 2^32-1), only some are valid for your program.  One way to get a good pointer by doing `la` with a global data label.  Global data starts at 0x10010000 (by default), and goes on from there depending on how much global data you have allocated.  So, if a pointer doesn't look like something like 0x1001xxxx, then it is not a pointer to your global data.

Comment: File descriptors are not for dereferencing; they are for passing to certain ecalls.  You can use the debugger to view memory with or without the `lb`.

Comment: Every process has an [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), and for a 32-bit program we consider that it is a 4GB address space, but only some of the memory within the address space is allocated to the process; some is allocated to your code, some to your data, some to stack, some to heap, and, some to IO devices like keyboard MIMO or bitmap display.  Memory accesses outside of those things are usually are mistakes (and even some within those areas are mistakes, too, but the processor doesn't necessarily catch those).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is check all values in the buffer and do some arithmetic to calculate the center of mass of a certain area. So I have to pass the three RGB values into registers for each pixel. I'm not sure how to do this without lb. Because I have to hold the values.

Comment: You can use `lb`, just use a valid pointer value with it.

Comment: The assembly code is reading only 3 bytes in total from the file as compared with the C code which reads a lot more bytes 3*Width*Height.  You also need to make sure that the Open ecall succeeds as these simulators are notorious for not finding files to open unless they are under their noses.  If you have an additional question, search for an answer and post a new question if you can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I fixed the code, and here are the mistakes I've fixed:

- I wanted to read all values into the buffer. The file contains 172800 values since the resolution of the picture is 320x180. And there are three values per pixel (RGB components). I've assumed that the max. length flag for reading system calls should be 3 because of the RGB values. After changing it to 172800 it read the whole file into the buffer.
  `li a2, 172800`
- I tried to load bytes with `lw` instruction instead of `lbu`. Each value has a size of a byte and should be stored as unsigned.
- Finally, I checked if the file was opened correctly by checking if the file descriptor equals zero.